# Is there any way to merge overlapping audio segments into one with very low latency?

Tags: python, arrays, audio, pydub

I've this problem where I'm faced with overlapping audio segments: in particular, audio segment `t` overlaps with audio segment `t+1` in the last couple of words (e.g. `t = "I like to move"` and `t+1 = "to move in circles all day"`). Is there any way that I can merge the 2 audio segments so that they sound smooth? I've tried doing something the following:

```
curr_audio = curr_audio[len(prev_audio):] #Where both items are PyDub AudioSegments
```

but that does not seem to solve it and only gives me the final part of the audio segment with non-overlapping parts missing. Am I doing something wrong here? I've also tried working with bytes and doing a similar approach to above, but it seems like the byte streams of the generated audios are completely different which makes this problem super hard.

Is there a nice way to do this in near real-time?

Edit of a working example:

Here's sample 1: https://vocaroo.com/14ygGStF6788
Here's sample 2: https://voca.ro/18S4ZjSwgjey

Comment: It depends on the sort of data you are dealing with. If it is PCM audio and the overlap is always the same number of samples, you _should_ be able to simply merge them at the overlap. You could also apply a window or a fade at the overlap as well. For instance, `t = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and  `t+1 = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]` then the overlap  is `2` or, in DSP terms, the "hop size" is `3` You mention doing things in real-time, which would suggest you are handing buffers of audio in a loop somewhere. There would really need to be a minimal working example before a definitive answer could be given

Comment: @fdcpp indeed I am handling buffers in a loop, but I've tried to minimize my example to this problem as that's what I'm currently facing. I have two consecutive audio samples, one which overlaps with the other at the beginning of the next one. All I need to do is chop off the overlap so it sounds natural. I will update with 2 audio samples if that makes it easier?

Comment: The concept of hop is pretty clear, best make sure you have [your head wrapped around it](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/36509/why-is-each-window-frame-overlapping). But what is not clear is wether the overlap is always the same number of samples in length or if it varies

Comment: @fdcpp it’s the same number of words but that does not guarantee it being the same length in terms of audio spoken

Comment: If you don't have timestamps of when the words are spoken, the number of samples overlap is variable, the length of each buffer is variable, and, I suspect, the sample values also do not match in the overlap, then you indeed do have quite a tricky problem. If all of the above is true, I would actually start looking at how you are interacting with the API and try to get yourself in situation where you can guarantee some of the above first.

Comment: @fdcpp do you know how accurate + fast force alignment algorithms are when it comes to 2-3 second samples?

Comment: This is isn't just a question of force alignment as the lack of timestamps is not the only problem to solve.  I would say that is unlikely to work in "real-time" but given you are discussing audio data 2-3 seconds in length we might need to define what "real-time" is in this case. I have checked the mp3 files linked and the overlap is not data that matches. That means you _will_ need to know timestamps of words before you could think about cross-fading between them.

Answer (score 0):

Merging two audio clips to make them sound smooth requires some audio editing skills. You can use some professional audio editing software to achieve this goal, such as Audacity, Adobe Audition, etc. These software have some features that can be used to process audio overlap and transition.

However, if you want to solve this problem programmatically, you can use some Python libraries to process audio files. For example, you can use the pydub library to load, process, and save audio files.

This is a basic step that you can refer to:

First, you need to determine the overlapping part of the two audio clips. You can determine this by listening to the two audio clips, or if you have more precise information, such as the waveform of the audio or the metadata of the audio, you can use these data to determine the overlapping part.
Then, you can use the AudioSegment class of pydub to load your audio file. You can create an AudioSegment instance from an audio file using the from_file method.
For the overlapping part, you may need to create a new AudioSegment with a length equal to the length of the overlapping part of the two audio clips. Then, you can use this new AudioSegment to replace the beginning part of the second audio clip.
Finally, you can use the concatenate method to merge two audio clips together. This method will merge two AudioSegment instances into a new instance.
You can use the export method to save your results. This method saves the AudioSegment instance as an audio file.
Please note that due to the complexity of audio processing, the above steps may require some adjustments to suit your specific situation. You may need to spend some time adjusting these steps to achieve the results you want. You may also need to consult the documentation of pydub to better understand how to use this library.